# Unable to read params in site response url in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting response like this from the Client :

```
http://192.168.25.241/CPMO.asmx?wsdl|context=
{transaction_id=9610842, ref_id=14943018526993, 
service_id=CPA_MCOM_999, error_list=n/a, sub_eff_date=201705121715460, 
notification_ind=2, error_code=1, destination_mobtel=0105660125, 
keyword=dummy, CURRENT_STEP=0, sub_exp_date=201705131200000}
```

Note :

```
?wsdl|context=
{transaction_id=9610842, ref_id=14943018526993, service_id=CPA_MCOM_999, error_list=n/a, sub_eff_date=201705121715460, notification_ind=2, error_code=1, destination_mobtel=0105660125, keyword=dummy, CURRENT_STEP=0, sub_exp_date=201705131200000}
```

So How can I read this string within the `{}`, after reading the parameters, redirect to the particular URL (I mean above URL), Can anyone help me in C#?

Comment: "i am getting response like this from the client". I think you mean "request", not "response"? If you have a webservice, the client makes a request, and you (the webservice) send back a response. Anyway, this set of parameters...it's not JSON, it's not XML and it's not a normal set of querystring parameters. So it'll come all inside one parameter I think, and then you'll have to parse it out yourself. Or you could tell the client their request is nonsense and demand they send it in a recognised format.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the string as explained below.

```
var text = "{transaction_id=9610842, ref_id=14943018526993, service_id=CPA_MCOM_999, error_list=n/a, sub_eff_date=201705121715460, notification_ind=2, error_code=1, destination_mobtel=0105660125, keyword=dummy, CURRENT_STEP=0, sub_exp_date=201705131200000}";

//replace {} from your string.

var dict = text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split('='))
           .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```